# Bad: java xsd generation

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am trying to generate the classes of an xsd in java with netbeans using the jaxbinding tool, but when it comes to doing it, it generates the following errors:

```
[ERROR] 'AcceptedIndicator' is already defined
  línea 21 de file:///C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facturacion%20Electronica/XSD/UBL2/common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  línea 21 de file:/C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facturacion%20Electronica/XSD/UBL2/common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd
```

Virtually all the components of the CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd file say that they are repeated.

In the file DIAN_UBL.xsd does the following imports

```
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" schemaLocation="C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facturacion Electronica/XSD/UBL2/common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" schemaLocation="C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facturacion Electronica/XSD/UBL2/common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" schemaLocation="C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facturacion Electronica/XSD/UBL2/common/UBL-CommonExtensionComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<import namespace="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1/Structures" schemaLocation="DIAN_UBL_Structures.xsd"/>
```

In the fourth import, in the file DIAN_UBL Structures.xsd it makes the following imports:

```
<import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
<import namespace="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" schemaLocation="http://www.dian.gov.co/micrositios/fac_electronica/documentos/common/UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule-2.0.xsd"/>
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" schemaLocation="http://www.dian.gov.co/micrositios/fac_electronica/documentos/common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
```

When I remove the import that is (UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd) repeating, another error occurs that says that it is missing that import so that the tags are valid.

Some help? I would thank you a lot.

Comment: if you're missing imports can you autofix the imports through the IDE?  ctr shift i for me, on linux.  perhaps post your build file if necessary.